# How insert an image in footer of excel document with phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to insert dinamically an image in the footer of an Xlsx document, using PHPSpreadsheet library.

I tried to modify the sample of documentation, but nothing appears when I print the doc.

```
$inputFileName = './tpl1.xlsx';

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooterDrawing();
$drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
$drawing->setPath('./uploads/blu.png');
$drawing->setHeight(36);
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($drawing, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooter::IMAGE_FOOTER_CENTER);
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&G');
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the setOddHeader

```
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&G');
```

to

```
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&C&G');
```

The `HeaderFooter::IMAGE_FOOTER_CENTER` and `&C&G` must correspond each other.
You should set a width e.g.: `$drawing->setWidth(800);`

The fullcode should look like this:

```
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooterDrawing();
$drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
$drawing->setPath('./uploads/blu.png');
$drawing->setWidth(800);

$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($drawing, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooter::IMAGE_FOOTER_CENTER);
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&C&G');
```